# Linear transformation from a vector space to a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Can anyone help me with the following question:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$, possibly not finite dimensional. Let $T \colon V \to F$ be a linear map. Prove that there is no subspace $U$ such that $U$ contains $\ker(T)$ but is strictly not equal to $\ker(T)$ or $V$.

Comment: I have managed to prove the finite case using the rank nullity theorem. However, I got stuck when I attempted to prove the infinite case.

Comment: consider for a fixed nonzero $x_0 \in V$ : $x \to T[x] x_0 $ which is a rank $1$ linear map $V \to V$

Answer (score 0):

This is because $T$ is either $0$ or surjective, hence the quotient space $V/\ker T$ has dimension $0$ or $1$, and the subspaces of $V/\ker T$ correspond bijectively to the subspaces of $V$ which contain $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the contrary. Let $y \in U\backslash \ker (T)$ and $x \in V \backslash U$.
Then $\{x, y \}$ is linearly independent over the underlying field $F$. Set $W = F\{x,y\}$. Then $W \cap \ker (T) = \{0\}$. On restricting $T$ to $W$ one gets a monomorphism, which is impossible since $\dim_{F} W = 2 \neq 1 = \dim_{F}F$.